# Flutter, getting the most important device information

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) to get the device info for both Ios and Android.

I want to use a unique identifier (device id) for each user to add to a database, but I don't know which properties to store and with which ID.

So here's the question: Out of all of the settings below, which ones are important to store in a database? And which one is the unique device id? (For **Ios** and **android**)

```
Map<String, dynamic> _readAndroidBuildData(AndroidDeviceInfo build) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'version.securityPatch': build.version.securityPatch,
      'version.sdkInt': build.version.sdkInt,
      'version.release': build.version.release,
      'version.previewSdkInt': build.version.previewSdkInt,
      'version.incremental': build.version.incremental,
      'version.codename': build.version.codename,
      'version.baseOS': build.version.baseOS,
      'board': build.board,
      'bootloader': build.bootloader,
      'brand': build.brand,
      'device': build.device,
      'display': build.display,
      'fingerprint': build.fingerprint,
      'hardware': build.hardware,
      'host': build.host,
      'id': build.id,
      'manufacturer': build.manufacturer,
      'model': build.model,
      'product': build.product,
      'supported32BitAbis': build.supported32BitAbis,
      'supported64BitAbis': build.supported64BitAbis,
      'supportedAbis': build.supportedAbis,
      'tags': build.tags,
      'type': build.type,
      'isPhysicalDevice': build.isPhysicalDevice,
      'androidId': build.androidId,
      'systemFeatures': build.systemFeatures,
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _readIosDeviceInfo(IosDeviceInfo data) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'name': data.name,
      'systemName': data.systemName,
      'systemVersion': data.systemVersion,
      'model': data.model,
      'localizedModel': data.localizedModel,
      'identifierForVendor': data.identifierForVendor,
      'isPhysicalDevice': data.isPhysicalDevice,
      'utsname.sysname:': data.utsname.sysname,
      'utsname.nodename:': data.utsname.nodename,
      'utsname.release:': data.utsname.release,
      'utsname.version:': data.utsname.version,
      'utsname.machine:': data.utsname.machine,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android you want the `androidId`. According to the docs this

> is unique between the device + user and app signing

For iOS you want `identifierForVendor`. According to the docs this is a

> Unique UUID value identifying the current device.

Both of these are said to be unique identifiers, so they should be able to be used for identification in your database without generating conflicts.